# ¿Cómo redirecciono a una carpeta de mi proyecto haciendo uso de .htaccess de Apache?

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Tengo un proyecto creado en *Laravel* (PHP). Uso *xampp* durante el desarrollo ya que estoy aprendiendo a programar. El hecho es que tengo varios proyectos dentro de la carpeta `htcdocs`. Uno de ellos está ubicado en la carpeta `htcdocs/visualizador` (es el que me interesa). Para poder ingresar a la web tengo que escribir en el navegador `localhost/visualizador/public`. Lo que quiero lograr es que al escribir `localhost/visualizador`, sea redireccionado automáticamente a la carpeta `public` (que está en la ruta `visualizador/public`). 
He tratado de hacerlo escribiendo el siguiente código dentro del *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ /visualizador/public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Y si lo haces únicamente con una redirección en PHP o JavaScript? Incluso podrías hacerlo con HTML.

Comment: Como se haría eso?? XD

Comment: Un index dentro del directorio visualizador, con cualquiera de los métodos de redirección que te menciono. Pero prueba primero la respuesta que te han dejado hace un momento, es más, es más práctica.

Answer (score 2):

Sin complicaciones, si quieres redireccionar usa la directiva `Redirect`.
La puedes agregar en el mismo `.htaccess`.

En el caso  de subdirectorios, para evitar recursión usa `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch ^/visualizador$ /visualizador/public
```

De cualquier manera la reescritura sería:

```
RewriteRule ^visualizador/?$ visualizador/public [L]
```

La clave está en `/` inicial y final y el contexto de la regla. 
- Cuando la regla es a nivel Directory o htaccess la cadena de comparación no incluye el `/` inicial.
- Por lo regular los navegadores añaden automáticamente un `/` al final.

Comment: Probé con lo que me dijiste pero me redirecciona muchas veces y termina abortando la conexión 
La página no está siendo redireccionada correctamente es el mensaje que devuelve el navegador y aparece en la barra de direcciones: **localhost/visualizador/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public**

Comment: `RedirectMatch “^/visualizador$” /visualizador/public` <<<--- eso no funciona, no hace nada..

Comment: Disculpa, el tecladito de cel me andaba traicionando. Actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Disculpa, pense que se había solucionado pero sigue sin redireccionar. Probé con la última: RedirectMatch "^\/visualizador$" /visualizador/public

Comment: ¿Pones sólo el directorio en el broswer? Prueba sin `/` al final ¿O vas a usar algún recurso (html,php,etc)?

Comment: Si, la ruta que escribo en el browser es localhost/visualizador pero en las últimas respuestas simplemente no hacen nada..